# Buttons On Two Fragments Overlapping

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, overlapping

So I have two fragments, say Fragment1 and Fragment2 . And both has its own layout file. On first fragment (Fragment1) there are six buttons. So when I click on first button, I want it to display the Fragment2 But both are overlapping when I Click on the first Button.

Check Screenshot Below

THIS IS THE FRAGMENT1

[image]

THIS IS THE FRAGMENT2 AND It's Overlapping WITH FRAGMENT1

[image]

I Used Every Possible Solutions But None Works. 
i set background to white or black even images. none works.

My code on mainActivity

```
    public void button1click (View view) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag1,new Fragment2());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
}
```

Fragment1

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
public class onClicks extends AppCompatActivity {
}
View myView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);
    return myView;
}}
```

Fragment2

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
public Fragment2 () {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2_layout, container, false);
}}
```

fragment1_layout.
[This is fragment1_layout](https://pastebin.com/UGxu5dPH)

fragment2_layout.
[THIS is the fragment2_layout](https://pastebin.com/r7wcD9TW)

Please check what's wrong.

Comment: Is fragment 1 added dynamically to the view as well? Or is it static inside of activity's layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs suggest you always use FrameLayout to replace fragments. I see this problem in your code in this line

```
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag1,new Fragment2());
```

It seems you don't have a container (FrameLayout) to replace your fragments in it.  To fix this possible design issue , you should create an xml for your Main Activity there add a FrameLayout with id "container" for example. Then, use it in code this way

```
public void button1click (View view) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,new Fragment2());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
}
```

Then you should in onCreate() method of your activity add fragment1 to your container so that you don't get blank screen when opening the app